# My 2002 95 v6 saab wont start

Tags: saab, cranks-wont-run

### Saab 95 3.0 v6 turbo wagon arc

I basically know nothing about Saabs but I know cars quite well.

My Saab died - it fully cranks but won't start. Now what lead to this was that I was driving to work and my dash started lighting up like a Christmas tree, check engine, abs, low voltage, ect. It then had barely any power going up hill then died of a dead battery.

I got a jump but it only lasted maybe 10mins then fully died and refused to start even with a fully charged battery. Now by a process of elimination all fuses and relays checked out. There was no fuel pressure but came to find out no power getting to the fuel pump. Attached external power to the fuel pump it works but still no start. Now I'm told that if the crank sensor does not work it wont engage the fuel pump so I replaced that with a new one. Still no start. I read that the ignition cassettes go bad a lot checked for fire no fire come to find out they're not getting power as well.

**In short:**

1. The car turns over but does not run
2. No power to fuel pump (works tho) or Ignition cassettes
3. All fuses are fine and work
4. replaced crank sensor & park neutral switch

Comment: Double check fuse 14 (30A) in the under dash fuse box. If that doesn't have power check Fuse 2 (60A Maxi Fuse) in the maxi-fuse block near the battery. If that fuse is OK jump power to terminal 30 of the main relay and double check power to the ignition modules and fuel pump. The fuel pump has nothing to do with the crank sensor. It's a simple on off circuit.

Comment: WIS: "As soon as the control module [Trionic 7] receives pulses from the crankshaft sensor, it grounds [turns on] the fuel pump relay."  Just like on the more-common T7 engines.  It also throws P0337 if there are no pulses during starter motor operation; any codes?

Answer (score 1):

The Christmas tree sounds like the alternator died.  My car stopped running, in the case of my alternator dying, soon after the radio went out, so the critical voltage for T7 might be pretty high.

Answer (score 0):

Clean battery terminals and main grounds, and re-tighten.

If you can get it to attempt to start and you have poor running conditions, or failure to stay running, it's likely due to Vacuum issues. These Saab's are excessively dependent on vacuum, and a leak can cause all kinds of gremlins.